# Exception: waiting for alert to be present

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I need to open a site that contain authentication alert.
To handle that alert I tried following code but no success:

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
     alert.authenticateUsing((Credentials) new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "pass"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Alert not found");
}
```

Exception occur is:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 100 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's an alert and not a modal?

Comment: Let me share a screenshot

Comment: @FDM added a screenshot to a question please see

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, that's a basic authenticatin popup.

The easy way to bypass this in Selenium tests is to insert the username and password in the URL, like so:

```
@driver.get 'http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth'
```

More info: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/13-work-with-basic-auth
Let me know if this works for you!

**Alternative 1**
Using AutoIt, or Windows API which is same as alternative 3 but proper code. See the answers in [this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357634/selenium-autoit-script-to-handle-windows-authentication-pop-up-on-chrome).

**Alternative 2**
See Mike's answer [in this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888323/how-to-override-basic-authentication-in-selenium2-with-java-using-chrome-driver) on how to create a Chrome extension to bypass the popup

**Alternavite 3 (works but quick & dirty)**

```
using System.Windows.Forms
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
SendKeys.SendWait("username");
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
SendKeys.SendWait("password");
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: Okay I just tried your solution, site successfully opened but again the popup raised

Comment: Do you have an Url where I can test this popup?

Comment: Yes Please: https://www.engprod-charter.net/

Comment: See my edits for some alternatives which work (I have personally tried alternative 3)